Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to set property 'CaptchaWord' on object of type 'BlazorCaptcha.Captcha'
I use a nugget package that named is BlazorCaptcha in my Blazor project. My project is built and displaying on browser successfully. But BlazorCaptcha tag disappear from the page and in the console of browser is logged such an error:

Unhandled exception rendering component: Unable to set property 'CaptchaWord' on object of type'BlazorCaptcha.Captcha'. The error was: The type initializer for 'SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo' threw an exception

The captcha nugget that I'm using is https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorCaptcha
Thank you.


Could you please provide the sample code which you are using. the issue seems to be related the library you are using. which version you are using? make sure that the library is being copied to the output directory. try to install the latest version of the SkiaSharp or BlazorCaptcha. make sure you have added the reference of the libraries in the project
